# Armadillo C++:- Efficient access of columns in a cube structure

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

Using Armadillo matrix library I am aware that the efficient way of accessing a column in a 2d matrix is via a simply call to .col(i).

I am wondering is there an efficient way of extracting a column stored in a "cube", without first having to call the slice command?

I need the most efficient possible way of accessing the data stored in for instance (using matlab notation) A(:,i,j) . I will be doing this millions of times on a very large dataset, so speed and efficiency is of a high priority.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want

```
 B = A.subcube( span:all, span(i), span(j) );
```

or equivalently

```
 B = A.subcube( span(),  span(i),  span(j) );
```

where `B` will be a row or column vector of the same type as `A` (e.g. containing `double` by default, or a number of other available types).

Comment: I believe that returns a mat. Ideally I need a vec to be returned.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't careful and didn't test.  This will return a vec, I have used this a lot.  You are reducing to just a column -- so the matrix will in fact be a row or col vector.  I have now edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks I will go and give it a try.

Comment: It appears that using subcube is very slow. I just tried doing a cube vs a std::vector<mat> and then performing an all pairs sq distance calculation on the elements and the vector<mat> approach took a 1/3 of the time.

Comment: Given there is a .memptr() operation. I presume there is a way of using that to get the cols out using that???

Answer (score 1):

.slice() should be pretty quick. It simply provides a reference to the underlying Mat class. You could try something along these lines:

```
cube C(4,3,2);
double* mem = C.slice(1).colptr(2);
```

Also, bear in mind that Armadillo has range checks enabled by default.  If you want to avoid the range checks, use the .at() element accessors:

```
cube C(4,3,2);
C.at(3,2,1) = 456;
```

Alternatively, you can store your matrices in a field class:

```
field<mat> F(100);
F(0).ones(12,34);
```

Corresponding element access:

```
F(0)(1,2);      // with range checks
F.at(0).at(1,2); // without range checks
```

You can also compile your code with ARMA_NO_DEBUG defined, which will remove all run-time debugging (such as range checks). This will give you a speedup, but it is only recommended once you have debugged all your code (ie. verified that your algorithm is working correctly). The debugging checks are very useful in picking up mistakes.